# getting errror while inheriting res.users into new model

Tags: odoo, odoo-12

I am trying to inherit res.users model of odoo12 but getting an error.
My code is as follows:

```
model.py
class SaleIndividual(models.Model):
    _name = 'sale.individual'
    _inherit = 'res.users'
    individual_description = fields.Char()

view.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<odoo>
  <record id="view_form_sale_custom_individual" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">Individual Form</field>
    <field name="model">sale.individual</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
      <form string="Individual">        <group>
        <field name="name" />
          <field name="individual_description" />
          <label for="login" class="oe_edit_only" string="Email Address"/>
                            <h2>
                                <field name="login"
                                        placeholder="email@yourcompany.com"/>
                            </h2>
        </group>
      </form>
    </field>
  </record>

  <record id="view_tree_sale_custom_individual" model="ir.ui.view">
     <field name="name">Individual Form</field>
    <field name="model">sale.individual</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <tree>
              <field name="individual_description" />
            </tree>
    </field>
  </record>
```

> duplicate key value violates unique constraint
> "res_groups_users_rel_gid_uid_key"
>
> DETAIL: Key (gid, uid)=(1, 1) already exists.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to inherit `res.user` you need to write the code as below:

Use like below:

```
class SaleIndividual(models.Model):
     _name = 'sale.individual'
     _inherit​s = 'res.users'
​
     name = fields.Char()
     email = fields.Char()
     individual_description = fields.Char()
```

Comment: I want to make a separate table in db for my new model which inherits res.users